# laravel slow query issue optimization

Tags: php, laravel

I want to optimize my query as it is taking long to run with current eloquents. I have two table, toys and product.
From each product one is reserved as sample of toy if not than it has to be updated as sample by the query so what i'm doing right now is below.

```
$toywithsample=product::select('toyid')->groupBy('toyid')->where('sample','yes')->get();
```

Above code is to get id of all the product with which have their one sample from in its product

```
$toywithoutsamples=toy::select('id')->whereNotIn('id',$toywithsample)->get();
```

Above code is to get id of all product which have no sample toy in

```
 foreach($toywithoutsamples as $toywithoutsample){
      $product=product::where('toyid',$toywithoutsample->id)
                        ->where('sample','sale')->limit(1)
                        ->update(['sample'=>'yes']);
}
```

Below is table structure

toy table

id,name,

product

id, toyid,sample

Comment: You should define relations between the two, and use proper Laravel naming conventions, that way you can simply query through the relations - then you can probably just update it in one bulk instead of querying them individually. Essentially, you can turn these 3 queries (where one is in a loop, which is usually poorly designed) and turn it into a single or two queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
$toys_ids_with_sample = Product::where('sample', 'yes')->get()->pluck('toyId');


// get the products grouped by toyId.

$products = Product::whereNotIn('toyId', $toys_ids_with_sample)->where('sample', 'sale')->get()->groupBy('toyId');

// get the product ids whose sample field you want to change to
// yes.

$update_product_ids = [];
foreach($products as $toyId => $products){
  // We will only pick the first one, as we have to change just 1.
  array_push($update_product_ids, $products->first()->id);
}


Product::whereIn('id', $update_product_ids)->update(['sample' => 'yes']);
```

This reduces the total number of queries.